# Take output from a detached screen running a server application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, remote, gnu-screen

I wish to fetch output from a screen running a Minecraft bedrock server, after executing list command to list online people on the server using

```bsh
screen -X stuff 'list\n'
```

I wish to gain the output of this for use further in a python script as such, a file would be easy as then i can fetch everything after select few lines.
I tried server logging but ended up with a bodge attempt of repeatedly attempting to remove log file, enable logging again and then executing the above command via

```bsh
rm screenlog.0
screen -X log
screen -X stuff 'list\n'
```

What I was wondering was if there is a better way to do it.
Tail isnt an option as multiple things can effect stdout in the screen.

Comment: I don't know Minecraft at all. In general a good server would open a port on `localhost` for `telnet`/`nc` communication, or it would provide a socket. You connect to it when the server runs, send a command, receive a response, disconnect. Proper protocol should return the response to the command only, not all real-time messages that are generated, unless you ask it to. Easy and straightforward. Is Minecraft server good enough to provide such interface? I found [this](https://github.com/kirsle/minecraft-control/blob/master/README.md) but I don't know how it handles the "response only" rule.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thats a wonderful resource but is unfortunately for the java edition...